# The sum of the digits is incorrect. Why?

Tags: python

i can't understand why the output of my code concatnates the digits instead of showing their sum:

```
#Get a number, and show the number of digits and the sum of the digits.
num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
j = 0
i = 1
k = 0
while i < num:
    i = i*10 
    j += 1
    k += (num - k)%i
print (f' The number has {j} digit(s), and the sum is: {k}')
```

Comment: And what is the output?

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. Where it says `k += (num - k)%i`, what is the intended purpose of this line? In particular, what should be the largest possible value that ever gets added? How many digits would that have? Now, think carefully about where `i` comes from. Will this `% i` have the desired effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the code. Let's say `num = 432`:

```
i = 1 * 10 = 10
j = 0 + 1 = 1
k = 0 + (432 - 0)%10 = 2
---
i = 10 * 10 = 100
j = 1 + 1 = 2
k = 2 + (432 - 2)%100 = 2 + 32 = 34
---
i = 100 * 10 = 1000
j = 2 + 1 = 3
k = 34 + (432 - 34)%1000 = 34 + 398 = 432
```

This algorithm is most definitely not adding every digit. There are several ways to do what you intend in python. One way is inputting the number as a string and summing every digit casting them as integers inside a generator:

```py
num = input('Enter a number: ')
total = sum(int(digit) for digit in num)
print(total)
```

If you want the number to be an integer since the beginning, you can also do this:

```py
num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
total = 0
while num > 0:
    digit = num%10
    total += digit
    num /= 10  # num //= 10 in python 3
print(total)
```

Comment: `sum([int(digit) for digit in num])` will create a list unnecessarily. You can leave the brackets out and have `sum` operate on a generator instead of a list, like so: `sum(int(digit) for digit in num)`

Comment: Absolutely right